# htaccess redirect URL with specific sub domain to another URL

Tags: php, node.js, .htaccess, redirect, cakephp

1. I have my website made in Cake PHP.
2. I want to redirect all the requests with http://api.domain.com to http://localhost:3000 (which is a node endpoint)
3. But I still want requests with www.domain.com or domain.com to target my Cake PHP website.

This is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Kindly help...

Comment: I think Nginx should be used for such purposes. It can easily be used as a proxy for http://localhost:3000

Comment: Yup, you’re right! Duh, why I didn’t think of this. Sometimes you just get so engrossed with a problem that you can’t think of simple solutions.